# Can I pass a global var to an underscore view?

Tags: backbone.js

I wonder if possible to do pass a global variable when rendering a template. Basically I get this variable each time I call a controller, so it looks like this:

```
 window.myVar = 0;
 //this var will change in a given moment when I make a request to the server.. so:

 //into the render method of my view, I have something like this:
 var template = _.template($("#myTemplate").html(), { varIwantToPass : myVar } );
 this.$el.html(template);
```

this way I can access it into the template with something like this:

```
 <%= varIwantToPass.get('myVar') %>
```

if this possible?; and also, each time a render the view, this code will excute again and update the value?

Comment: Note that you can't `_.template(source, data)` as of Underscore 1.7, you have to `t = _.template(source); h = t(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, except you template has to be

```
<%= varIwantToPass %>
```

and pass variable as window.myVar so you would not accidentally replace it

And yes it will update after each render if you pass the variable each time

Working example:

Html:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
    <%= varIwantToPass%>
</script>

<div></div>
```

JS:

```
window.myVar = 'a';
var templateHtml = $("#myTemplate").html()
var render = function () { 
    var template = _.template(templateHtml, { varIwantToPass : window.myVar } );
    return template;
}

$('div').html(render());

window.myVar = 'b'; //change variable
setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').html(render());
}, 1000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omynhL1d/

However I would advocate on not using global variable and instead saving it somewhere in your backbone view or even better a model and then render by listening on that model change event

Comment: No problem. I have added jsfiddle example and please check the last suggestion on not using global variable.